# Can you trace the source for a Timeout expired error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two identical sql server databases - staging (version 10.0.4000.0) and testing (10.0.2531.0).
I have a Visual Studio 2008 ASP.Net, C# project that calls these databases.  The project uses .xsd to return data from stored procedures.

There are over 100 stored procedures in this project and everything works great. However, I recently created a stored procedure that is giving me issues.  The stored procedure runs in both databases from QA.  When I create the table adpater for the xsd and connect it to the testing db, it runs as expected.  When I change the connection to the staging db, I get this error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

The procedure requires two date parameters.  If I remove the date paramters, the error goes away and I get the expected result set.  If I put in a bogus string or integer parameter, it also runs.  But if I require dates, the timeout error occurs.  Keep in mind that the stored procedures are identical in test and staging and both return results (in 3 seconds) when run in QA.  I'm just clicking on the tableadapter and selecting the preview data option so I know this can't be some mistake in my presentation code.

I'm not sure what code to provide or what might help solve this issue.  Please let me know what details may help and I can provide.

**UPDATE**:
Here is the full message returned from Visual Studio:

> MW.MWDeptTotalSpend.Fill,GetData (@StartPYMNT_DT, @EndPYMNT_DT) could
>   not be previewed.
>
> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

**UPDATE 2:**

I made a small change in my sproc that may give some insight.

```
WHERE X.PYMNT_DT BETWEEN '1/1/2014' and '5/1/2014' --@StartPYMNT_DT AND @EndPYMNT_DT
```

The commented parameters are defined @StartPYMNT_DT smalldatetime, @EndPYMNT_DT smalldatetime

The procedure returns data now, but obviously I want to pass in my date parameters.

Comment: Do you happen to have a ton of data in the staging one? Sounds like that particular query is taking *really* long.

Comment: Can you run the procedure in Management Studio with the same date parameters and get results?

Comment: Only 239 rows of data are returned in staging.  I can run the procedure in Management studio without any issue at all.  It only takes 3 seconds to return the 239 records.

Comment: 3 seconds is a long time for only 239 rows.  What indexes do you have in place?

Comment: Good point.  This stored procedure queries a view with 40k records and then does a rollup on a union.  I don't have any indexes on the view, but the underlying tables have an identity as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "solution."  For some reason, I had to cast the datetime parameters as datetime in the sql:

```
X.PYMNT_DT BETWEEN CAST(@StartPYMNT_DT as smalldatetime) AND CAST(@EndPYMNT_DT  as smalldatetime)
```

I would still like to know how to trace the source of these errors, and obviously this solution is a hack.  I would be willing to accept a better answer if someone can supply one.